# How to solve file not found problem in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, location, tkinter.iconbitmap

I had made a program where I require files from that directory where the python file is located. The files are located in the same folder where the python file located.

I can't write the full path of the file in the python script
I used the **./** method in the script but it gives error

Please help me to solve the problem

here is my code

'''

#code

```
root=Tk()
root.title("SOHAM YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER")
root["bg"]='#1F1F1F'
root.iconbitmap("./img/youtube_(1).ico")
root.geometry("900x680")

file =PhotoImage(file="./img/youtube-icon.png")
headingIcon=Label(root, image=file)
headingIcon.pack(side=TOP, pady=3)
```

'''

My folder location

[image: here img is my required folder in YOUTUBE_VEDIO_DOWNLOADER.py which is my python file]

Here **img** is my required folder in **YOUTUBE_VEDIO_DOWNLOADER.py** which is my python file

My script error is given below

```
y"python "e:/python projects/YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python projects\YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER\YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py", line 215, in <module>
    root.iconbitmap("./img/youtube_(1).ico")
  File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2073, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "./img/youtube_(1).ico" not defined
```

Comment: To show code, put three _backticks_ \`\`\` before and after the block of code. NOT single quotes.

Comment: The error obviously means that the file does not exist.  I have tested your code without the ico file, it shows the same error.  Then I just create an *empty* ico file (file size is zero) and the script runs without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `__file__` variable, then get its parent.

Example:

```py
from pathlib import Path

my_dir = Path(__file__).parent
```

Later on, you can use `my_dir` directly if the function understand `Path` objects, or `str()` it first:

```py
# if root.iconbitmap accepts Path objects
root.iconbitmap(my_dir / "img/youtube_(1).ico")

#or

# if root.iconbitmap does not accept Path objects
icopath = str(my_dir / "img/youtube_(1).ico")
root.iconbitmap(icopath)
```

Comment: Sure it works. I see no error message from you, so it works.

Comment: ERROR
$ python "e:/python projects/YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python projects\YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER\YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py", line 220, in <module>
    root.iconbitmap(icopath)
  File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2073, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "e:\python projects\YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER\img\youtube_(1)" not defined

Comment: from pathlib import Path
my_dir = Path(__file__).parent
icopath = str(my_dir/ "./img/youtube_(1)")
root.iconbitmap(icopath)

Comment: Is your file named `youtube_(1)` or `youtube_(1).ico` ? Also, next time you should just edit your question, saying you're trying out my suggestion, and put in the error message there.

Comment: my file is youtube_(1).ico

Comment: Sorry sir I forget to say that I had tried your code and also thank you for spend time to solve my problem

Comment: @SOHAMDASBISWAS. Well, if an answer works for you, please mark the answer with a checkmark. That indicates to others that the problem is solved and there's a satisfactory solution.